# Triangular inequality condition

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have to calculate the following table

```
Table[
  ThreeJSymbol[{j1, 0}, {j2, 0}, {j3, 0}],
  {j1, 1, j1max}, {j2, 1, j2max}, {j3, 1, j3max}
];
```

in such a way that $|j_1-j_2| \le j_3 \le j_1+j_2$.

How can I write this command?

Comment: `Table[If[ 
  Abs[j1 - j2] <= j3 <= j1 + j2, {{j1, j2, j3}, 
   ThreeJSymbol[{j1, 0}, {j2, 0}, {j3, 0}]}, ## &[]], {j1, 1, 
  j1max}, {j2, 1, j2max}, {j3, 1, j3max}]` - added values where condition holds so you can see what's happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have the range of j3 dependent on j1 and j2. That can be easily written directly in the Table command:

```
Table[ThreeJSymbol[{j1, 0}, {j2, 0}, {j3, 0}], {j1, 1, j1max}, {j2, 1, j2max}, {j3, Abs[j1 - j2], j1 + j2}]
```

the value for j3max is therefore no longer needed.